# String to array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I'm trying to convert an input string `"[f1 f2]"`, where both `f1` and `f2` are integers, to an array of two integers `[f1 f2]`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way by using sscanf:

```
f = sscanf(s, "[%d %d]", [1 2]);
```

where s is the array-like  string and f the new array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `str2num`:

```
f = str2num( "[123 456]" )
% f = [123, 456]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing together with [`strsplit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)

```matlab
my_str = "[32 523]";
split_str = strsplit(my_str, ' ');  % split on the whitespace
% The first cell contains "[32" the second "523]"
my_array = [str2num(split_str{1}(2:end)) str2num(split_str{1}(1:end-1))]
my_array = 
           32  523
```

When you have more numbers in your string array, you can lift out the first and last elements of `split_str` out separately (because of the square brackets) and loop/`cellfun()` over the other entries with `str2num`.